# sed multiple replacements with line range

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file with below records

```
user1,fuser1,luser1,user1@test.com,data,user1
user2,fuser2,luser2,user2@test.com,data,user2
user3,fuser3,luser3,user3@test.com,data,user3
```

I wanted to perform some text replacements from

user1,fuser1,luser1,user1@test.com,data,user1

to

New_user1,New_fuser1,New_luser1,New_user1@test.com,data,New_user1

so I wrote below sed script.

```
sed -i -e 's/user/New_user/g; s/fuser/New_fuser/g; s/luser/New_luser/g' file
```

This works perfect. Now I have a requirement that I want to replace in specific line range.

```
start=2
end=3
sed -i -e ''${start},${end}'s/user/New_user/g; s/fuser/New_fuser/g; s/luser/New_luser/g' file
```

but this command is replacing pattern in all lines. example output is,

```
user1,New_fuser1,New_luser1,user1@test.com,data,New_user1
user2,New_fuser2,New_luser2,user2@test.com,data,New_user2
user3,New_fuser3,New_luser3,user3@test.com,data,New_user3
```

Looks like range is getting applied only to first expression and remaining expressions are getting applied on whole file. How to apply this range to all expressions?

Comment: I don't think that `sed` script _works perfect_: `New_user1,fNew_user1,lNew_user1`. What is your expected output with that input data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` variables to use for this functionality, controlling the row and column numbers used for replacing

```
awk -vFS="," -vOFS="," -v columnStart=2 -v columnEnd=3 -v rowStart=1 -v rowEnd=2 \
     'NR>=rowStart&&NR<=rowEnd{for(i=columnStart; i<=columnEnd; i++) \
           $i="New_"$i; print }' file
```

where the `awk` variables `columnStart`, `columnEnd`, `rowStart` and `rowStart` determine which columns and rows to replace with `,` as the de-limiter adopted.

For your input file:-

```
$ cat input-file
user1,fuser1,luser1,user1@test.com,data,user1
user2,fuser2,luser2,user2@test.com,data,user2
user3,fuser3,luser3,user3@test.com,data,user3
```

Assuming I want to do replacement in lines 2 and 3 from columns 3-4, I can set-up my `awk` as

```
awk -vFS="," -vOFS="," -v columnStart=3 -v columnEnd=4 -v rowStart=2 -v rowEnd=3 \
     'NR>=rowStart&&NR<=rowEnd{for(i=columnStart; i<=columnEnd; i++) \
           $i="New_"$i; print }' file
user2,fuser2,New_luser2,New_user2@test.com,data,user2
user3,fuser3,New_luser3,New_user3@test.com,data,user3
```

To apply on the say the last column, set the `columnStart` and `columnEnd` to the same value e.g. say on column 6 and on *last* line only.

```
awk -vFS="," -vOFS="," -v columnStart=6 -v columnEnd=6 -v rowStart=3 -v rowEnd=3 \
     'NR>=rowStart&&NR<=rowEnd{for(i=columnStart; i<=columnEnd; i++) \
           $i="New_"$i; print }' file
user3,fuser3,luser3,user3@test.com,data,New_user3
```

Answer (score 1):

When using GNU Sed (present on Ubuntu, probably Debian, and probably others).

There is a feature which makes this easy:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands

> A group of commands may be enclosed between { and } characters. This
>   is particularly useful when you want a group of commands to be
>   triggered by a single address (or address-range) match.
>
> Example: perform substitution then print the second input line:

```
$ seq 3 | sed -n '2{s/2/X/ ; p}'
X
```

Given the original question, this should do the trick:

```
sed -i -e '2,3 {s/user/New_user/g; s/fuser/New_fuser/g; s/luser/New_luser/g}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
START=2
NUM=1
sed -i -e "$START,+${NUM} s/user/New_user/g; $START,+${NUM} s/fuser/New_fuser/g; $START,+${NUM}  s/luser/New_luser/g" file
```

As you can see, there are several changes:

1. The line range has to be present at each expression
2. The range should be represented (in this case) as the start line number and number of lines (the number of affected lines is NUM+1)
3. You put extra apostrophe symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `s` command:

```
start=1
end=2
sed -e "$start,$end s/\([fl]*\)user/New_\1user/g" file
```

`[fl]*user` will match `user` with optional `f` or `l` first letter

**output:**

```
New_user1,New_fuser1,New_luser1,New_user1@test.com,data,New_user1
New_user2,New_fuser2,New_luser2,New_user2@test.com,data,New_user2
user3,fuser3,luser3,user3@test.com,data,user3
```